# How to adopt Ranger policy in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-ranger

I am using Spark 3.0.1 on HDP 3.1.4. Everything is running well except Spark SQL can't honor Ranger standard SQL policy.

In the past days, I tried the solution which found from the community, the hive warehouse connector and spark-authorizer and spark-llap.
Unfortunately I can't solve it. Seems the code was not maintained and the latest release version doesn't support Spark 3.0.  I saw many people are also struggling in this problem.

Is there any suggestion to make Spark SQL adopt Ranger column/ row level permission policy ? Any idea are appreciated. Thank you.

1. hive warehouse connector, it works on spark 2.3.1, but not 3.0.
2. spark-authorizer, spark-llap both are version not compatible error.

The version is Spark 3.0.1, HDP 3.1.1, Hive 3.1.0, Ranger 1.2.0

Comment: Any resolution?